# Getting output in console but not in page in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

```
<div>
 <input type="radio" id="normal" name="radioOption" onchange="enableTxt(this)" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="luxury" name="radioOption" checked="checked" onchange="enableTxt(this)"/>
</div>


<script>
    function enableTxt(elem) {
        var id = $(elem).attr("id");

         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/index",
        data : { radiovalue: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        });

    }
</script>
```

By passing the value i  tried to run a php query.But it didn't work.But i got the output in console.I need to get the output in select option.Can any one please help??

Comment: Also for your url `url: "<?php echo base_url('home');?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax post is not handling the return.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/index",
    data : { radiovalue: id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);//json object            
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting the response on the php file.but its not working

Comment: You have to parse the response and add the response items to your options. This code is not enough to add the response to the options.

Comment: in console i can see the value.but its not working in the site page

Comment: Not exactly sure what your problem is.

Comment: i ve got the response value  in the php page.I tried to run a php query using that value.i got the output in console but i don't know how to get it in the view page

Comment: So you ran a query and have the response of the query? If it is an array use die(json_encode($queryResults));  This will return the queryResults in a JSON format to the javascript codes success function.

Comment: great.I got the response in console. can you please tell me how to get these response in the same view page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131221/discussion-between-cyriac-and-illuminati).

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

```
var id = $(elem).attr("id");

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "test.php",
data : { radiovalue: id},
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

And add below code in your php file. It's display Value.

```
echo $_POST['radiovalue'];
```

Comment: got the output.but how can we run an another php query using the output.

Comment: i am stuck in that

Comment: A simple echo of radiovalue will not work if the javascript is expecting datatype: 'json'